# Dimension of a polytope cut with a hyperplane

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, polytopes

Let $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be a convex polytope and let $H \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be a hyperplane with two sides $H^+$ and $H^-$. Let $V$ be the vertex set of $P$. Suppose $V = A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are non-empty and disjoint, and where $A \subseteq H^+$ and $B \subseteq H^-$. I want to show that $\dim(P \cap H) = \dim(P) - 1$.

Basically I'm cutting a polytope in half and I want to show the dimension decreases by one. This should be a simple question but after many many hours thinking about it I have made no progress. Any help?

Comment: Your polytope $P$ and hyperplane $H$ have the same dimension?

Comment: I'm not assuming anything about the dimension of $P$. The hyperplane $H$ of course has dimension $d-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are asking is somwhat connected to the quite old one, which relates a (convex) polytope's vertex definition to its according hyperplane (aka facet) description.

Suppose that one to be solved already. Then your polytope $P$ will be described by its set $S$ of hyperplanes (spans of facets). Now consider the intersections $h_i = s_i \cap H$ for each $s_i\in S$ (possibly empty). Obviously the set of the non-empty $h_i$ then represents a subdimensional hyperplane description of $H\cap P$.

Again you might want to convert that one in turn into its vertex description. It then will be happen that every vertex from that new vertex set $V'\subset H$ clearly must be a point on one of those former edges of $P$ between a point of $A$ and a point of $B$, i.e. the intersection of that edge with $H$.

--- rk

Comment: The equivalence of convex hulls of finite sets of points and bounded intersections of half-spaces is clear to me. It is also clear that a vertex of $H \cap P$ comes from an edge of $P$. However, it is not clear to me that  I can find $d$ affinely independent vertices in $P \cap H$, which I would need to show that $\dim(P \cap H) = d-1$.

Answer (score 1):

A convex polytope $P$ in $\mathbb R ^d$ is by definition the convex hull of a finite number of points. It is usual to show that this is equivalent to the intersection of a finite number of half-spaces $S_{i, i=1\dots k}$, where this intersection is non-empty and bounded.

We assume WLOG that $P$ has dimension $n$, and we can work in $\mathbb R ^n$: either $n=d$, or the polytope is "flat" in one or more dimensions, and we place ourselves in an affine subspace $E$ that contains $P$ and has same dimension. Then the new $S'_i$ are the intersection of the previous $S_i$ and $E$.

When we cut $P$ with an hyperplane $H$ of $\mathbb R ^d$, there are $2$ cases: $H \cap E = E$, or $H \cap E \subsetneq E$.
If $H \cap E = E$, as $P\subset E, P \subset H$, so the vertex set of $P$ cannot be decomposed into $A$ and $B$ non-empty with $A \subseteq H^+$ and $B \subseteq H^-$. So this case does not happen.

We are left with $H \cap E \subsetneq E$. In this case, as $E$ is an $n$-dimensional affine subspace, $H' = H \cap E$ is an $n-1$ dimensional subspace, i.e. an hyperplane of $E$.

For each point $b \in P' = P \cap H'$, we know that depending upon where $b$ is situated in $P$, its neighborood in $P$ will be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R ^n$ (if $b$ is in the interior of $P$, "interior" being relative to $\mathbb R^n$), or to a half-space of $\mathbb R ^n$ (if $b$ is on the frontier of $P$).
If $b$ is in the interior of $P$, we can find an open neighborood $N$ of $b$ such that $N \subset P$. Then $N$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, it has (topological) dimension $n$. In $P'$, $N' = N \cap H'$ has then dimension $n-1$, as $H'$ is an hyperplane of $E$. This shows that dimension is reduced by $1$.

Comment: To me it appears that you did not use the assumption that some vertices of $P$ are on one side of $H$ and some are on the other side. Without this assumption the claim isn't true: if we have for example $P \subseteq H$ then $P \cap H = P$ so the dimension did not go down at all.

Comment: @HigherMoonTheory Thanks for noting that. I assumed that we were cutting with an hyperplane of $\mathbb R ^d$. The trouble comes from the fact that the original hyperplane of $\mathbb R ^N$ might project into the full $\mathbb R ^d$. I'll change the answer to be clearer.

Comment: @HigherMoonTheory Modification done. I also changed the symbols ($n$, $d$, $N$, $H$ etc.) so that they are more consistent and do not clash with your own. That being said, the proof is difficult as some concepts have more than one possible definition (typically: _dimension_).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. A couple of points: First, by "dimension" I mean the dimension of the affine hull. Second: You said "I assumed that we were cutting with a hyperplane of $\mathbb{R}^d$", and indeed we are cutting $P$ with a hyperplane of $\mathbb{R}^d$. So the polytope $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ can have any dimension and $H \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ has dimension $d-1$. Thus $\dim(H) - \dim(P)$ can be as large as you want. To me it looks like your cutting the polytope with something whose dimension is one less than the polytope which maybe still confuses me a little.

Comment: @HigherMoonTheory Part of the confusion comes from the fact that my comment is no longer aligned with what $d$ means in the answer, sorry for that.

Comment: @HigherMoonTheory I say the polytope has dimension $n$ and is included into an  $n$-dimension affine subspace $E$. So we don't use anymore $\mathbb R ^d$, we use $E$ which is equivalent to $\mathbb R^n$. In $E$, the cutting hyperplane $H$ reduces to $H'=H \cap E$. The case $H'=E$ is discarded so $H'$ is strictly included in $E$ and has dim $n-1$. So yes, in $E$ we cut the polytope with something whose dimension is one less than the polytope.

Comment: @HigherMoonTheory As for the dimension, I use the topological notion, i.e. any interior point has a neighborood homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. That's because it is clear for me that the intersection of an $n$-dim-homeomorphic neighborood by an hyperplane is an $n-1$-dim-homeomorphic neighborood; it is less clear for me that the intersection of the convex hull of $n$ linearly independent points with an hyperplane is the convex hull of $n-1$ linearly independent points.